# how do i run this custom api?? (using wix and javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, slider, web-testing, velo

Im trying to code a slideshow that starts on a different page depending on the week day
im using wix to build this website but ive run to a stop

```
    $w.onReady(function() {
   $w("#slideshow1")
});
const  d = new Date(); // gets time

function func2() { d.getDay } //gets day of the week

if (func2.getDay = 0) { $w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(0)}
else if (func2.getDay = 1) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(1);}
else if (func2.getDay = 2) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(2);}
else if (func2.getDay = 3) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(3);}
else if (func2.getDay = 4) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(4);}
else if (func2.getDay = 5) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(5);}
else if (func2.getDay = 6) {$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(6);}
// sets slideshow according to day
```

ive tried using all lines as "if's"

if anyone knows thier way around the velo/wix api id love some help on this as ive sat for hours troubleshooting

thx

Comment: Use double (or triple) equals for comparison.  Call the getDay function with parens.  All your if clauses should look like `if (func.getDay() == 1)` etc.

Comment: i did this and it seems to almost work but now it wont let me use the func, i get an error saying Property 'getDay' does not exist on type '() => void'.

Comment: You're not returning anything from *func2* so the value is undefined. *getDay* is a method of *Date* instances, you need to call it to get the result, so `function func2() {return d.getDay()}`. But you really don't need *func2* anyway: `if (d.getDay() == 0) { ... }`. Consider replacing *func2* and everything below with `$w("#slideshow1").changeSlide(d.getDay())`.